# sequelize-typescript audit log for create update delete

Tags: sequelize-typescript

I would like to log all actions(create, update, delete), for the update preferred to log the old value and new value that updated through the sequelize-typescript. But I have no idea how to achieve this. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the CLI then you can add in the environment variable `DEBUG=sequelize` and you will get detailed SQL statements.

For using the library in Node, when you create the DB instance you can pass in a verbose flag that would log out that information. You won't get the before and after values but you will get the SQL commands being sent to the database.

```js
const myVerboseDb = new Sequelize(config.db, config.username, config.password, {
  host: "localhost",
  port: "3456",
  dialect: "postgres",
  logging: true // This line will tell Sequelize to log all SQL commands
})
```

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/610#issuecomment-69675229

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html#logging